# Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'webhive_manageurl.id_webhive_manageurl' in 'where clause'

Tags: magento-1.9, upgrade, query

Insert Query working:

```
$data = array('title'=>'hello there','content'=>'how are you? i am fine over    here.','status'=>1);
$model = Mage::getModel('mynews/mynews')->setData($data);
try {
    $insertId = $model->save()->getId();
    echo "Data successfully inserted. Insert ID: ".$insertId;
} catch (Exception $e){
 echo $e->getMessage();   
}
```

update query having issue:

```
$id = 2;
$data = array('title'=>'hello test','content'=>'test how are you?','status'=>0);
$model = Mage::getModel('mynews/mynews')->load($id)->addData($data);
try {
    $model->setId($id)->save();
    echo "Data updated successfully.";

} catch (Exception $e){
    echo $e->getMessage(); 
}

a:5:{i:0;s:234:"SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'webhive_manageurl.id_webhive_manageurl' in 'where clause', query was: SELECT `webhive_manageurl`.* FROM `webhive_manageurl` WHERE (`webhive_manageurl`.`id_webhive_manageurl`='4')";i:1;s:1878:"#0 C:\wamp\www\majento\lib\Varien\Db\Statement\Pdo\Mysql.php(110): Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array)
#1 C:\wamp\www\majento\app\code\core\Zend\Db\Statement.php(291): Varien_Db_Statement_Pdo_Mysql->_execute(Array)
#2 C:\wamp\www\majento\lib\Zend\Db\Adapter\Abstract.php(480): Zend_Db_Statement->execute(Array)
#3 C:\wamp\www\majento\lib\Zend\Db\Adapter\Pdo\Abstract.php(238): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('SELECT `webhive...', Array)
#4 C:\wamp\www\majento\lib\Varien\Db\Adapter\Pdo\Mysql.php(428): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('SELECT `webhive...', Array)
#5 C:\wamp\www\majento\lib\Zend\Db\Adapter\Abstract.php(756): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->query(Object(Varien_Db_Select), Array)
#6 C:\wamp\www\majento\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Resource\Db\Abstract.php(380): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->fetchRow(Object(Varien_Db_Select))
#7 C:\wamp\www\majento\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Abstract.php(225): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Abstract->load(Object(webhive_ManageUrl_Model_ManageUrl), '4', NULL)
#8 C:\wamp\www\majento\app\code\local\webhive\ManageUrl\controllers\Adminhtml\MyformController.php(17): Mage_Core_Model_Abstract->load('4')
#9 C:\wamp\www\majento\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Controller\Varien\Action.php(418): webhive_ManageUrl_Adminhtml_MyformController->postAction()
#10 C:\wamp\www\majento\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Controller\Varien\Router\Standard.php(250): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('post')
#11 C:\wamp\www\majento\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Controller\Varien\Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#12 C:\wamp\www\majento\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#13 C:\wamp\www\majento\app\Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#14 C:\wamp\www\majento\index.php(87): Mage::run('', 'store')
#15 {main}";s:3:"url";s:88:"/majento/index.php/manageurl/adminhtml_myform/post/key/141f405aa915852340dd4b97d47e8d3a/";s:11:"script_name";s:18:"/majento/index.php";s:4:"skin";s:5:"admin";}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your model definition and table definition do not match up. In particular, your model returns the wrong value for `getIdColumn()`.

When a model is saved that does not have a value set for the id column, Magento assumes an insert, which is why that works. When the id column is filled, it will first try to load the stored model, to determine if it should do an update or an insert with a fixed id, which is what you're seeing there.

Comment: Ok...
how to solve the issue?

Comment: The name of the id column looks strange to me. Can you show what the `_construct()` method of the model looks like and show the table structure?

Comment: Solved:
yes, the id name issue...
i changed from id_webhive_manage_url to id

Answer (score 0):

for Update case you did not need to set id it `primary key and has been already set`.

```
$data = array('title'=>'hello test','content'=>'test how are you?','status'=>0);
$model = Mage::getModel('mynews/mynews')->load($id)->addData($data);
try {
    //$model->setId($id)->save();

$model->save();
    echo "Data updated successfully.";

} catch (Exception $e){
    echo $e->getMessage(); 
}
```

Comment: i've tried:
    $model->save();
But didn't work... :(